# javascript doesn't work on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
            {
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                var data = 'id=' + id ;
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

                $.ajax(
                {
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "delete_row.php",
                       data: data,
                       cache: false,

                       success: function()
                       {
                            parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                       }
                 });                
            }
        });


        $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
    });

</script>
```

and this is what triggers it

```
<a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;">
```

i use it to delete database rows from mysql. It works well on firefox, safari, but nothing happens on internet explorer. I tried it on ie7 and on ie9 and no result. Can you give me an advice regarding my problem?

Comment: Any errors on the console? Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe IE doesnt like the # in your href tag. Have you tried using 'prevent default' to make sure it is only your javascript is running?

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` looks very fragile. You should use something along the lines of `$(this).closest("tr").attr("id")`

Comment: Is var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'); what you would expect it to be ? Also: var parent = $(this).parent().parent(); Maybe something's happening to your html on IE. Also I wouldn't advise using parent().parent() . try http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Prob not your problem but rather than using `var data = 'id=' + id;` use a key value pair `var data = {'id':id};`

Comment: maybe IE7 can't recognize the jquery library but i don't know why it's not working on ie9 try using a newer  version of your jquery library

Comment: As usual, start with defining what exactly doesn't work. Put some debugging lines (`console.log(data)`, for example) into your script to check its flow: this will help you to localize the problem.

Comment: I can't really speak from an AJAX perspective as I'm not experienced enough to address that specific issue. However, I can see that you're trying to see the background of a table row (tr) with the class of 'odd' to white (#FFFFFF). IE, for some reason, has trouble with this. You'll have to to $('#delTable tr:odd td).css('background','#FFFFFF'); in order for that visual styling to be applied to IE. I hope someone can help with the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `dataType:'html',` inside your ajax request.

Comment: I think Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html). We no need to specify